# C# refactoring a class with multiple dictionary properties

Tags: c#, dictionary, design-patterns, data-structures, refactoring

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class AbstractReportFeeInfo
{
    public decimal TotalFee { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<long, decimal> TitleFeeDictionary { get; set; }  

    public Dictionary<VRAbstractInterfaceData, decimal> VRAbstractFeeDictionary { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<lkaData, decimal> LKAAbstractDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Billing class that processes the costs of a report type depending on what type it is (title, vrAbstract or LKA). These classes are very different from eachother.

Putting three dictionaries in this AbstractReportFeeInfo class is the only solution I could come up with...But, as of now, in other parts of my code, I will have to do conditional logic to determine which report type is being called and then call the appropriate dictionary in this AbstractReportFeeInfo class. Is there a more standard way to handle this type of scenario? I tried to make the AbstractReportFeeInfo class only have one dictionary with key - object and value - dictionay, like this:

```
public class AbstractReportFeeInfo
{
     public decimal TotalFee { get; set; }

     public Dictionary<object, decimal> dictionary{ get; set; } 
}
```

But this doesn't really change much except now I still need conditional logic in other parts of my program, but then also need to explicitly cast to the appropriate data types.

Any ideas for how to design this is a more loosly coupled way?

Comment: Is `TotalFee` applicable to all report types?

Comment: Can you explain why everything is combined into the one `AbstractReportFeeInfo` class? Why not have three classes?

Comment: Yes, here is a little more info. So in the System, in the Billing Controller, only one report type will be used. A transaction can include multiple reports, so a List of reports (for example, a List of lkaData). The decimal dictionary value is to hold the cost of each individual report. The TotalFee prop holds the cost of the entire transaction. The dictionary is neccessary because some reports in the transaction can cost either the standard fee, or $0 if the report is eligible at no charge.

Comment: Then I feel you don't need `TotalFee` because it's total of all decimals from fees' dictionary.

Comment: So far, except `Fee` nothing can be abstracted across these report types. Even this may not be required. Can you show us controller code or part of code that you claim to have if else conditions on report type? On the other hand you said Billing controller will use only only one report type.

Comment: Doesn't the `AbstractReportFeeInfo` class contain the report type somewhere?